# How many maximal planar graphs are there?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, planar-graphs, computational-geometry, delaunay-triangulation

We denote by a *triangulation* a (simple) maximal planar graph. How many triangulations on $n$ vertices are there? How many triangulations are there if we cannot distinguish the vertices, i.e. isomorphic triangulations are seen as equal?

All results I can find are for plane graphs, i.e. concrete embeddings, and not abstract graphs.

Comment: I might be mistaken here but i thought maximal planar graphs have unique embeddings, so counting (non isomorphic) plane triangulations should be the same?

Comment: This question may be more suitable for math.stackexchange.